# saving data in database in cakephp2.x event function

Tags: database, cakephp, events, listener

I'm using event listener in cakephp for save notification after like posts
everything is ok and my event listener functions works good
but I think I cant access to my notification table from event function
this is my error:

```
Undefined property: AddNotification::$Notification [APP\Lib\Event\AddNotification.php, line 15]
```

this is my vote model for save likes:

```
App::uses('CakeEvent', 'Event');

class Vote extends AppModel {

    var $useTable = 'votes';

    public $actsAs = array('Containable');

    public $belongsTo = array('User','Tail');
    public function afterSave($created, $options = array()) {
       if ($created) {
            $event = new CakeEvent('Model.Vote.created', $this, array(
                'data' => $this->data[$this->alias]
            ));
            $this->getEventManager()->dispatch($event);
        }
    }
```

and my function in AddNotification.php:

```
<?php 
App::uses('CakeEventListener', 'Event');

class AddNotification implements CakeEventListener {

    public function implementedEvents() {
        return array(
            'Model.Vote.created' => 'addANotification',
        );
    }

    public function addANotification($event) {
        // Code to update votes
        pr($event->data['data']);
        $notified = $this->Notification->find('all',array(
            'conditions'=>array('Notification.user_id'=>$this->CustomAuth->User('id'),'Notification.tail_id'=>$this->data['tail_id'])
        ));
        // pr($notified);
        if(!empty($notified)) {
                $this->Notification->delete($notified[0]['Notification']['id']);
                $this->Notification->create();
                $notifi['Notification']['user_id'] = $this->CustomAuth->user('id');
                $notifi['Notification']['tail_id'] = $event->data['data']['tail_id'];
                if($event->data['data']['value']==1) {
                    $notifi['Notification']['message'] = "Tail has been liked";
                }
                else {
                    $notifi['Notification']['message'] = "Tail has been disliked";
                }
                if ($this->Notification->save($notifi)) {       
                    $message = 'notifi saved';
                }
                else {
                    $message = 'notifi not saved';

                }
        }
        else {
            $this->Notification->create();
            $notifi['Notification']['user_id'] = $this->CustomAuth->user('id');
            $notifi['Notification']['tail_id'] = $event->data['data']['tail_id'];
            if($event->data['data']['value']==1) {
                $notifi['Notification']['message'] = "Tail has been liked";
            }
            else {
                $notifi['Notification']['message'] = "Tail has been disliked";
            }
            if ($this->Notification->save($notifi)) {       
                $message = 'notifi saved';
            }
            else {
                $message = 'notifi not saved';

            }
        }
    }
}

 ?>
```

please help me to improve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Undefined property: AddNotification::$Notification [APP\Lib\Event\AddNotification.php, line 15]

The error is pretty clear? What makes you think that you can magically access a non existing property of a model instance somewhere?

You need to load the model instance first.

```
$notification = ClassRegistry::init('Notification');
$notification->find(/*...*/);
```

You'll get the same error for this line

```
$this->CustomAuth
```

It looks like you have no understanding of how the objects are passed around and instantiated in this scenario. The code looks like you've simply copy and pasted controller code into a listener class. This won't work. Spend some time on trying to understand the MVC architecture and how events work beyond triggering them. Explaining you all of the implications I see here is simply to long.